# BadMatch and BadWindow in Urban Terror

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics, games, vulkan

I get an error whenever I try to launch Urban Terror in Vulkan mode (opengl works fine) . I have googled and found nothing.

Here is the error message: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JUWo0WzlXYuPlRvLpLoa-x8IJkshIPP_GUu0ogffGNs/edit?usp=sharing

Turning off fullscreen fixes the badwindow bugs, but it gives this error at the end:

---

> Sound memory manager started
>   Loading vm file vm/ui.qvm...
>   VM file ui compiled to 592390 bytes of code
>   ui loaded in 16778240 bytes on the hunk
>   Received signal 11, exiting...
>   ----- Client Shutdown (Signal caught (11)) -----
>   ----- Client Shutdown (Server fatal crashed: VM_Free(ui) on running vm) -----   WARNING: Recursive CL_Shutdown()
>   ----- Client Shutdown (VM_Free(ui) on running vm) -----
>   WARNING: Recursive CL_Shutdown()
>   Sys_Error: VM_Free(ui) on running vm

---

CPU: Intel Celeron N3350
GPU: Intel HD 500
OS: Ubuntu 18.04